# Comments not showing after successful prints

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I'm trying to build a comment feature, where it fetches the documents for a post id and users the Comment Model to map the data to a readable view.

I have created a getComments command with a print statement at the end which has proved successful in displaying the data of the documents for that specific post.

My issue comes in displaying the data, I have created a ForEach statement but I when the view is shown, no data is present.

My code is below:

**CommentsViewModel**

```
class CommentsViewModel : ObservableObject{

@Published var comments : [Comment] = []
@Published var noComments = false
@Published var newComment = false
@Published var commentTxt = ""


let ref = Firestore.firestore()
let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid

var post: Post? {
    didSet {
        if let post = post {
            getComments(id: post.id!) { comments in
                print(comments)
            }
        }
    }
}

func getComments(id: String, completion: @escaping([Comment]) -> Void) {
    Firestore.firestore().collection("posts").document(id).collection("comments")
        .order(by: "timestamp", descending: true)
        .getDocuments { snapshot, _ in
            guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else { return }
            let comments = documents.compactMap({ try? $0.data(as: Comment.self) })
            
            completion(comments)
        }
}


  }
```

**CommentsView**

```
struct CommentsView: View {
@StateObject var commentsData = CommentsViewModel()

let post: Post

var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        VStack(spacing: 15){
            Text(post.id)
            ForEach(commentsData.comments) { comment in
                CommentsRow(post: post, comment: comment, commentData: commentsData)
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .padding(.bottom,55)
    }
    .onAppear {
      commentsData.post = post
    }
}
}
```

**CommentsRow**

```
struct CommentsRow: View {

var post : Post
var comment : Comment
@ObservedObject var commentData : CommentsViewModel
let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid

var body: some View {
    Text(post.id)
    Text(comment.id)
}


}
```

What could be the problem here?

Comment: just after your `print(comments)`, add  `self.comments = comments`

Answer (score 0):

I added self.comments = comments after the print statement and now everything works :)